# Как вложить один json в другой?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

C сервера приходит такой json:

```
{  
    2:{  
        name:"Ноутбуки"
    },
    3:{  
        name:"Флешки"
    }
}
```

А также такой:

```
{  
    5:{  
        name:"Physics"
    }
}
```

Как мне из двух json получить один вида:

```
{  
    2:{  
        name:"Ноутбуки",
        {  
            5:{  
                name:"Physics"
            }
        }
    },
    3:{  
        name:"Флешки"
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. У вас  ошибка в результате - лишние скобки вокруг `5: { name: "Physics" }` 2. Переводите обе строки в объекты, объединяйте и переводите назад в JSON

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объединение - это [`extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
var obj1 = {
    2:{
        name:"Ноутбуки"
    },
    3:{
        name:"Флешки"
    }
};
var obj2  = {
    5:{
        name:"Physics"
    }
};
jQuery.extend(obj1, obj2);
```

В `obj1` теперь будет:

```
 {
    2:{
        name:"Ноутбуки"
    },
    3:{
        name:"Флешки"
    },
    5:{
        name:"Physics"
    }
};
```

Если сделать так `jQuery.extend(obj1["2"], obj2);`, то в `obj1` будет:

```
{
    2:{
        name:"Ноутбуки",
        5:{
             name:"Physics"
        }
    },
    3:{
        name:"Флешки"
    }
};
```

Comment: а как можно именно вложить в  2:{  name:"Ноутбуки", {   5:{   name:"Physics"  } }

Comment: @КонстантинКостылев такой json не валиден. У вас для объекта `{ 5:{  name:"Physics" }}` ключ не задан в этом json'е.

Comment: {'1':{'name': "NAME", '2':{'name':'ChildrenNAME'} } } 1 - ключ, остальное значение, name - ключ, NAME - значение, 2 - ключ, name:"ChildrenName" - значение

Comment: @КонстантинКостылев `jQuery.extend(obj1["2"], obj2);`